# Create user via scim in WorkPlace

Tags: facebook, scim

I've got a problem to create an user in WorkPlace via scim and javascript.
Here is my code :

```
var url2 = "https://www.facebook.com/company/xxxxxxxxxxx/scim/Users/";
  var options2 = {
    'method' : 'POST',
    'headers': headers,
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    //body: JSON.stringify(userJson),
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
    //body: userJson
    'body': JSON.stringify({"userName":"xxx.xxx@xxxxxx-group.com","name":{"familyName":"Jensen","givenName":"Barbara"},"active":true,"schemas":["urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"]})
  };
  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2,options2);
```

But this code return an error :

```
[17-04-26 07:55:39:939 PDT] {
   "Errors": [
      {
         "description": "[field:schemas]Invalid Request: Your request can't be parsed or has incorrect syntax.",
         "code": 1789003
      }
   ]
}
```

Any idea about the solution ?
Thanks
JPA

Comment: Do not try to scrape Facebook. Use the API.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.simplecloud.info/#implementations

[SCIM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9H8R.png)

```
POST /v2/Users  HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer h480djs93hd8
Host: example.com
Content-Length: ...
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"],
  "externalId":"bjensen",
  "userName":"bjensen",
  "name":{
    "familyName":"Jensen",
    "givenName":"Barbara"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These errors usually comes when you are not passing mandatory attributes in the workplace for creating the user.

Include the below attributes in your create requests and check -

a. userName

b. name

c. active